# Find a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the second-order partial derivatives $f_{xy}(0, 0)$ and $f_{yx}(0, 0)$ exist but are not equal.

So I need a function of $x$ and $y$ where $f_{xy}(0, 0)\ne f_{yx}(0, 0)$.

So looking at $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$:

$f_x(x,y)=2xy^2$

$f_{xy}(x,y)=4xy$

$f_y(x,y)=2x^2y$

$f_{yx}(x,y)=4xy$

This function obviously fails, but I'm trying to find an example and I'm having trouble. I obviously need an some terms added, but the added terms will be killed off by the second partial derivative... So any hints?

Comment: I think that might be impossible to find since dxy = dyx.

Comment: You are going to need the second order mixed partials to be discontinuous, since if they are continuous they will be equal. So the problem with the example you tried is is that it's a smooth function (i.e. infinitely differentiable).

I suspect there is an example of the form $f(x,y) = $ some rational function undefined at $(0,0)$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, because of the [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27s_theorem), the function cannot have continuous second partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

[Here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/MixedPartialDerivatives.pdf) there is an example.

And [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5841.pdf) (page 20) there is a reference for the following interesting facts.

- There exists a function $f$, the mixed second derivatives of which exist at every point but such that $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$ on a set of positive measure.
- There exists a function $f$, the mixed second derivatives of which exist almost everywhere and such that $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Let $~~f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{x^2+y^2},~ & \text{if}\ (x,y) \ne  (0,0),\\
0, & \text{if}\  \text{if}\ (x,y) =  (0,0). \\
\end{cases}\\
$

We know by definition that
$\[f_{xy}(a,b)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f_y(a,b)\right)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f_y(a+h,b)-f_y(a,b)}{h}.\]$
\begin{equation}\label{pd.cdtwo16}
\text{Therefore, we have }~~~~~~~~~~f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\end{equation}

We have
[f_{y}(h,0)=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(h,k)-f(h,0)}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{ \frac{ hk\left(h^2-k^2\right)}{h^2+k^2}-0} {k}]
[=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{ h\left(h^2-k^2\right)}{h^2+k^2} =\frac{h^3}{h^2}=h.]
Also [f_{y}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{ 0-0}{k}=0.]
Therefore, \eqref{pd.cdtwo16} becomes
[f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h-0}{h}=1.]

Now, we have
[f_{yx}(a,b)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(f_x(a,b)\right)=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f_x(a,b+k)-f_x(a,b)}{k}.]
\begin{equation}\label{pd.cdtwo17}
\text{Therefore, we have }~~~~~~~~~~f_{yx}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f_x(0,k)-f_x(0,0)}{k}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\end{equation}

We have
[f_{x}(0,k)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,k)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \frac{ hk\left(h^2-k^2\right)}{h^2+k^2}-0} {k}]
[=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ k\left(h^2-k^2\right)}{h^2+k^2} =\frac{-k^3}{k^2}=-k.]
Also [f_{x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ 0-0}{h}=0.]
Therefore, \eqref{pd.cdtwo17} becomes
[f_{yx}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{0-k}{k}=-1.]
Thus, we have shown that $f_{xy}(0,0) \ne f_{yx}(0,0).\diamond$